# OpenSCAD 2d figure to 3d figure

Tags: 3d, 2d, openscad

I have a problem in OpenSCAD, I do know know language and I do not know to approach problem.
Lets say, I get 2d figure, for example circle(r=25) and I want to have solid from it. But what I want from that solid is.
-> On h=0,  there is my circle(r=25)
-> On h=10, there is a circle(r=35), so a circle, which is actually scaled, but I do not want to use scale, as it multiply a figure, but I want to make it 10 points bigger from every point in it
-> It looks like truncated cone
-> It works for othere figures, lets say polygons, still we have it 10 points bigger from every point
-> I need also something that works in reverse, I mean make figure smaller

How to approach it? Maybe there are examples on ner, so if you can show them to me, I will be gratefull

What I tried?
If h = 10, than for every h1 in [0, ..., 10] I tried to create something like that: (blech)

```
translate([0,0,h]) for(i = [0:359]){
                x = thickness*cos(i);
                y = thickness*sin(i);
                translate([x,y,0]) children(0);
                }
            }
```

Looks terrible, works terrible and is useless and I do no know how to make it to work, if I want smaller figure

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, if i understood your problem. But all you described above can be done with `linear_extrude()` and the scale-parameter:

```
small = 25;
large = 35;

// upscale 
linear_extrude(height = 10, center = false, scale = large/small) circle(r = small);

// downscale
translate([2*large,0,0]) {
    linear_extrude(height = 10, center = false, scale = small/large) circle(r = large); 
}
```

its working with every 2D-primitive and dxf-import.

Comment: it is not what i was looking for, and actually answer is to use minkowski

Answer (score 1):

Polygons can be [offset()](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/Transformations#offset) in both directions. As long as both resulting polygons are convex, it's possible to use hull() to generate a 3d object from them. Unfortunately hull() can't directly generate 3d from polygons, but that can be solved by a very thin linear_extrude().

```
$fa = 0.5;

module extrude(o, h) {
    hull() {
        linear_extrude(0.001)
            children();

        translate([0, 0, h])
            linear_extrude(0.001)
                offset(o)
                    children();
    }
}

extrude(10, 50) circle(20);

translate([80, 0, 0]) extrude(-10, 50) scale([1, 1.5]) circle(30);
```

For more complicated cases, there's some experimental example code in the [list-comprehension-demos](https://github.com/openscad/list-comprehension-demos) repository.